# Дублируются данные в модели DOM при обновлении

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

При обновлении страниц приложения (допустим, я возвращаюсь на предыдущую страницу и повторно перехожу на следующую) все данные на странице (заголовок и имя в навбаре, список свойств на странице и т.д.) удваивается, еще раз - утраивается, и т.д. Контент страниц у меня создается динамически - беру необходимые данные с сервера с помощью js и заполняю страницу. 
Никак не могу написать условие, чтобы при динамическом создании элементов на странице они проверялись на существование дубликатов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему-то ранее не получалось, но сейчас написал простое условие и пошло:

```
var elem1 = document.getElementById('userNAME');

    if (!elem1) {
        // Create username in the top navbar
    $(".userName").append($userName);
    } else {
        console.log("userName is exists");
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение вашей задачи достаточное простое.

Там, где данные нужно заполнять единично и блок гарантировано существует, делайте обновление всего блока, если конечно они изменяются с течением времени. Если данные неизменны на странице, то игнорируйте обновление при наличии данных в блоке.

```
//Если данных в блоке нет
if ($('#user_block').html().length==0) {
     //Вставить данные
}
```

Где необходимо добавлять и изменять существующие данные (например лента новостей), используйте специальный атрибут(ы) которые идентифицируют запись (блок), например время последнего обновления и id.

```
//получить блок по атрибуту data-id
var block = $("div[data-id='" + id +"']");

//Если блока не существует
if (block.length==0) {
   //Вставить блок с данными
}

//Если атрибут не равен дате последнего обновления
if (block.attr('data-update')!=lastUpdate) {
         //Обновить блок
}
```

Естественно, если блок гарантировано существует, достаточно использовать условие связанное с датой последнего обновления.

Основная концепция решения - просто проверять условия на определенных элементах при получении данных со стороны сервера. Хотя, так же было бы правильно устанавливать какой-нибудь **флаг**, если данные неизменны на странице, чтобы не запрашивать их лишний раз.

Comment: Спасибо, я параллельно свой ответ как раз писал) Не понимаю, почему ранее этот вариант не проходил, но, сейчас повторно попробовал и все сработало. P.S. Ваш вариант проанализирую также на будущее!

Comment: Почему-то условие: (//Если данных в блоке нет
if ($('#user_block').html().length==0) {
     //Вставить данные
} )   не работает...

Comment: Прошу прощение, работает - нашел в чем была ошибка - например, если между блоками div в html-разметке, есть хоть один пробел, работать не будет. Виной всему "красивое" форматирование кода с разносом тегов div на разные строки...